# how to undo rvm set stable?

Tags: ubuntu, rvm

I installed a rvm 2.0.0 and everything was ok
Then I made by mistake `rvm get head`
Then to correct that I added `rvm get stable`
But now when I try to `rvm install 2.0.0-study` (same error on `rvm install 2.0.0 -n study`) I get this ugly error

```
HEAD is now at 588c139 * remove trailing spaces.
remote: Counting objects: 9, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Total 5 (delta 4), reused 1 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (5/5), done.
From git://github.com/ruby/ruby
   08fbd2c..babae04  trunk      -> origin/trunk
Switched to branch 'ruby_2_0_0'
From git://github.com/ruby/ruby
 * branch            ruby_2_0_0 -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
error: pathspec 'tudy' did not match any file(s) known to git.
There has been an error while trying to checkout the source branch.
Halting the installation.
There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

How can I undo my rvm set stable ?...or fix this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `study` as name conflicts with `sha` selector for commits, you can check a whole list of disallowed names here http://rvm.io/rubies/named